# something wrong with this find statment cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i use two find statment..the first to fetch articles and the second to fetch comments that related with this articles...i see this error when use my code like this

```
Content:

    Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 27]

Created

    Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 31]

Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 73]
```

articles_controller.php

```
 function view($id=null) {

           $article = $this->Article->find('all', array(
      'conditions' => array(
        'Article.id'     => $id,
        'Article.status' => 1
      )
    ));

           $comment = $this->Article->Comment->find('all',
            array('conditions' =>
    array('Comment.article_id' => $id, 'Comment.status' => 1)));



              $this->set(compact('article','comment'));
              if(!empty($article)){

             // increment the number of items the dvd was viewed
                $this->Article->save(array(
                    'Article' => array(
                        'id' => $id,
                 'views' => ($article['Article']['views'] + 1)
                    )
                ));
              }
```

articles/view.ctp

```
     <!-- to show article title,image,content,date  -->
<div class="formats view">



<h2>Title: <?php echo $article['Article']['title']; ?></h2>

                       <dl>
    <dt>Image:</dt>
        <dd>   <?php
 echo $html->image($h,array('height'=>'250px', 'width'=>'280px')); ?>
 </dd>

                <dt>Content:</dt>
        <dd><?php echo strip_tags($article['Article']['content']) ; ?></dd>


        <dt>Created</dt>
        <dd><?php echo substr($article['Article']['created'], 0, 15); ?></dd>







           <!-- to show comments  related with articles -->
<?php if(!empty($article['Comment'])): ?>

    <div class="related">
        <h3>Comments For this Article</h3>
        <table>
            <thead>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($comment as $comments): ?>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Name,date</th>
         <td><?php echo '&nbsp;'.$comments['Comment']['name'].' &nbsp;&nbsp;'.substr($comments['Comment']['created'], 0, 15); ?> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                 <td><?php echo $comments ['Comment']['title']; ?></td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                   <th>content</th>
                    <td><?php echo $comments['Comment']['content']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

this database table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=47 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first find from this:

```
$article = $this->Article->Comment->find(
```

To this:

```
$article = $this->Article->find(...
```

(Notice the lack of "Comment" in the second one)

Also - there's really no reason you should need to write 2 separate queries - that's something CakePHP can handle easily for you with the [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable)

---

**NEXT FIX** (after changes were made from prev part of answer):

Do a print_r on your $article variable.  I assume you'll see that it should be:

```
$article[0]['Article']
```

instead of

```
$article['Article']
```

Comment: @user108047 - what's the SQL the Article->find is generating?  `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>` in your view

Comment: @user108047 - (added an 'Edit' to my answer)

Comment: when i change it to $article[0]['Article'] i see
 Notice (8): Undefined index: 0 [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 18]

Comment: when use <?php echo $article ['title']; ?> isee                   Notice (8): Undefined index: title [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 18]

Comment: when i use <?php  print_r($article); ?>    i see  Array ( )

Comment: Seriously - just print_r your array and show what it holds.  We're just guessing until you actually tell us what data you're getting.

Comment: I'm not joking here,, i tell you what happen Seriously because i need helping,,so again when i use this code <?php  print_r($article['Article']['title']); ?>     i see this error Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 91]

Comment: when i print <?php  print_r($article['0']['title']); ?> i see Notice (8): Undefined index: 0 [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 91]

Comment: when i use this   $article = $this->Article->findById($id); i see the data but i dont need to use this code because the condition status=1

Comment: Your query isn't returning any results.  That's your issue.  If you'd like to edit your question to add the query and show the results outside of cakephp, we can help you.  Currently, it's not a CakePHP issue, but a MySQL issue.

Comment: sorry but i see it is cakephp error,because when i use this statment i see all results good      $article = $this->Article->findById($id);
and when changed it like above i see all this error

Comment: user1080247 - the error you're getting is a PHP error because you're trying to access array content that doesn't exist.  The content doesn't exist because you MySQL query isn't returning any results.  And without knowing what that is, or what your DB looks like, it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: i added database table above.. and if you need any data i will give it to you.. if you need to upload full code i will do it

Comment: Post a few of the data of row(s) you think should be returned AND THE MYSQL QUERY GENERATED (per the last 4 times I asked you to do that).

Comment: You might have something WRONG with your Article.status. Is it really named `status` in your DB table? To test out, you should remove `'Article.status' => 1` from you code and see what happens. I run your code in my program and it is OK.

Comment: ALSO, the article status for the specific article you are opening in view might be set to something else not 1. If it is set to NULL for example nothing will be returned in your array. You should visit you DB and make sure that the Article.id you are calling has its status set to 1.

Comment: i removed 'Article.status' => 1 an i still see this error..Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 7]

Content:

    Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 12]

Created

    Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 16]

Notice (8): Undefined index: Article [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 57]

Comment: when use this code i retrive all data good..then it is not sql error $article = $this->Article->findById($id);

Comment: Please post the MySQL query generated - eg. "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE ..."

Comment: SELECT * FROM `Articles` WHERE `Article`.`id` = $id AND `Article`.`Status` =1

Comment: Please post things like this in your question.  If that's the MySQL, then that's your problem, as I highly doubt you have any items with id of '$id'.  My guess is that you posted the PHP though, and not the actual MySQL.

Comment: when use this code         $art = $this->Article->find('all',
          array(
         'conditions' => array('Article.status' => 1,'Article.id' =>$id ),
         'recursive' => -1 //int
            )
        );  i see SELECT `Article`.`id`, `Article`.`title`, `Article`.`content`, `Article`.`created`, `Article`.`modified`, `Article`.`views`, `Article`.`section_id`, `Article`.`status` FROM `articles` AS `Article` WHERE `Article`.`status` = 1 AND `Article`.`id` = 15

Comment: Does that query return a result(s) when you run it on your database?

Answer (score -1):

Hey instead of the following:

```
<?php echo $article['Article']['title']; ?>
```

try

```
<?php echo $article['title']; ?>
```

I am not sure yet why that happens, but it has worked for me in other occasions...

Also on the foreach statement for comments I noticed you have

```
<?php foreach($comment as $comments){ ?>
```

Which I dont think will display your comments correctly. You should have

```
<?php foreach($comments as $comment){ ?>
```

And in your controller for this, use

```
 $comments = $this->Article->Comment->find('all', ...
```

I am creating a similar application and at least that is how I handled everything.

If you need to, I will post back or email you my articles controller, comments controller and corresponding views for your review.

Thanks,

Comment: when use <?php echo $article ['title']; ?> isee Notice (8): Undefined index: title [APP\views\articles\view.ctp, line 18]

Comment: You have multiple things wrong with this answer.  1) when you do a find('all'), it won't return a single item like you're trying to get him to use in the first part.  2) his foreach is correct, yours is wrong (see his controller variable)....etc etc.