# how to add condition to pagination in cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

how to convert this statment to pagination with condition rules

```
  $comment = $this->Article->Comment->find('all',
            array('conditions' =>
    array('Comment.article_id' => $id, 'Comment.status' => 1)));
```

i do this but i get parce error

```
 var $paginate = array(
             'limit' => 5,
             'page' => 1,
             'order' => array('Comment.created'=>'desc'),
             'conditions' => array('Comment.article_id' => $id, 'Comment.status' => 1)
             );
$this->Article->Comment->recursive = 1;

this->set('comment', $this->paginate());
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?  ('this->set' should be '$this->set')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the step-by-step instructions [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Pagination.html#controller-setup).

Comment: Please try following the instructions and getting them to work, then tweak per your needs instead of going off on your own first and getting stuck on errors from things that weren't in the instructions.

Comment: var $paginate = array(
         'Comment'=>array(
         'limit' => 3,
         'page' => 1,
         'order' => array('Comment.created'=>'desc')
         ))
         ; $conditions ["Comment.status"] = 1;
         $conditions ["Comment.article_id"] = $id;
        $this->set('comment', $this->paginate($this->Article->Comment,$conditions));


          $this->set(compact('article'));
          if(!empty($article)){

Comment: Glad you got it to work! :)  If this was a helpful answer, please up-vote and accept as answer. Thanks.

Comment: you good man..although you ignore helpe me in this [link]question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645141/something-wrong-with-this-find-statment-cakephp-1-3/8645577#8645577)

Comment: I didn't ignore you - if you ever post what I requested, I'd be glad to look again.  Unfortunately, after asking 3-4 times for the MySQL that's generated (and even giving you the code for it), you still didn't add it.

Comment: what is mean of MySQL that's generated..if you mean sql table i already put it..if you mean sql dumb i already put it..and in the finish i added i put full code 21kb

Comment: if i don't understand your question sorry..put please explain.. i am beginner not advanced like you